# is it possible to draw multiple latitudes and longitudes in AGM (Angular Google Map) for tracking?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-maps, angular7, angular-google-maps

Im trying to do the vehicle tracking using AGM in Angular 7 where it is also necessary for me to show the path where the vehicle has travelled.

Right now i am  able to give only two locations which is the start location (**permanent**)  and end location(**keeps changing**) for drawing the path using AGM.

Then the tracking line directions change(**for ex: when the vehicle come back through the same route or near by route new tracking line is shown and when vehicle come back to the same location no tracking lines will be shown since starting point and end point is the same**)when i keep the starting point as static.

Instead is there any way for me to get the  multiple locations

if so once tracked line is kept there permanently even if the vehicle come back through the same route new line is drawn through the previous drawn line.